# Replying kafka template connect headers(CorrelationId) is not sent to Google pub sub

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use Replyingkafkatemplate, where correlationid is automatically added  but when the message is posted to Google pubsub, using kafka connector-Sink connector, the headers are missing. Only the message payload is present. 
Is there any way to get the headers in pub sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the [Cloud Pub/Sub Kafka Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector), then it does not yet support headers. There is an [outstanding pull request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/pull/200) under review to add this feature.

Comment: yes it is about Cloud Pub.Sub Kafka Connector. Thanks for the reply and update.